# C# access datagridview data by datagridview name

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have saved datagridview name in a string, how do I access my datagridview data by using the name of the datgridview? I do the following, but the datagridview is null.

DataGridView DGV = new DataGridView();
DGV.Name = "MyDataGridViewILikeToAccessWithData";

Answer (score 0):

You need to find Control in Form with `DataGridView` name as stored in string Variable. Then Cast this Control to `DataGridView`.

Comment: In form use code like Control cntrl =  Controls.Find("MyDataGridViewILikeToAccessWithData", true);

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you'll get from storing the data grid view name in a string is the data grid view name' what exactly are you trying to do?
In that case to access it you will need to use dgv.